# Where are GLKShaderBlockNode leaks coming from?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, glkit

After running the Leaks Instruments on an app that I am developing, I see a lot of leaks relating to `GLKShaderBlockNode`. Some are `GLKShaderBlockNode`, some are `Malloc < varying sizes >`, and some and `__NSCFString`.

I've searched for this online and at Apple's dev resources, but could find nothing about `GLKShaderBlockNode`.

Responsible Library : `GLKit`

Responsible Frame : `-[GLKShaderBlockNode copyWithZone:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project, the method "prepareToDraw" also cause the same leak.
I think it's because I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1, I call this method only for OpenGL ES 2.0.
After I delete the prepareToDraw calling, my project works well without the leak.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up getting rid of `GLKBaseEffect` and poof, all the memory leaks were gone. I had to write my own vertex and fragment shaders though.

Comment: How did you create this substitution ?

Answer (score 0):

Same leak here. And poor GLKit performance too.